# Concatenate a table name from a variable in a FROM clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to use a dynamically generated fully-qualified table name in sql server 2008.  For example, this does not work:

```
select max([id]) from @dbName+N'.[T1]'
```

This will give an error like:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 73
>
> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

I know that something like this works:

```
declare @qualifiedTable varchar(200) = @dbName+N'.[T1]'
select max([id]) from @qualifiedTable
```

But I have to do this LOTS of times so I would really like to do it in line.  Is it possible?

Comment: No, your other method won't work either. You need to build a script as a string and invoke it with either `EXEC (@string)` or `EXEC sp_executesql @string`, like in Duane Theriot's answer (make sure that @string is `nvarchar` then). Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136447/selecting-from-a-table-where-the-name-is-passed-as-a-variable "Selecting from a table where the name is passed as a variable") too.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, but one specific point here is that because your query does not include the schema, it will not work anyway. You need this: DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sp_executesql N'select (max([id]) from ' + @dbName + '.dbo.[T1]';
```

Comment: If `@dbName` is `varchar` (as opposed to **`nvarchar`**), you'll probably need to put `N` in front of one of the string constants in your expression, something like this: `sp_executesql N'select (max([id]) from ' + @dbName + '.[T1]';`, to make the result `nvarchar`, because that's the type `sp_executesql` expects for the argument representing the dynamic script.

Comment: You forgot the schema name, you need a three-part name to query an object in another database

Comment: That's a good point.  I added in the .dbo schema.  This should be replaced with the actual schema that is associated with "T1".  Also added the "N" suggested by Andriy.