# SQL Server 2008 SELECT * FROM @variable?

Tags: sql-server-2008, variables

It is possible?

```
DECLARE @vTableName varchar(50)

SET @vTableName = (SELECT TableName FROM qms_Types WHERE Id = 1)

SELECT * FROM @vTableName
```

I have this error:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Must declare the table variable
>   "@vTableName".

Comment: No, it's not possible as you're trying it. You'll probably get some answers using dynamic sql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting from a table where the name is passed as a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136447/selecting-from-a-table-where-the-name-is-passed-as-a-variable)

Comment: Could you tell us more about why you want to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo. Use dynamic SQL if you have to, but if you're structuring your tables in a way where you don't know the table name ahead of time, it might benefit you to rethink your schema.

Here is a great resource for learning how to use dynamic SQL: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 5):

if you're trying to select from a table of that name, then you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @vTableName varchar(50) 
SET @vTableName = (SELECT TableName FROM qms_Types WHERE Id = 1) 
EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM [' + @vTableName + ']')
```

Comment: No. OP is trying to dynamically get data from a table defined by a variable. Not simply trying to return the value of that variable.

Comment: OP is trying to SET the table name, and then select data from the table, not select the table name.

Comment: Your own edit invalidates your answer, since the variable `@vTableName` is **not** a table variable; it's a `varchar(50)`.

Answer (score 2):

my solution for this:

```
EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM  ' + TableName + '')
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though different folks are interpreting the OP differently.

I'm pretty sure the OP is asking for this type of concept / ability / maneuver...

"Put a table name into a variable and then use that variable as though it were a table name."

```
DECLARE @TableIWantRecordsFrom varchar(50)
--      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SET @TableIWantRecordsFrom = (SELECT TableName FROM qms_Types WHERE Id = 1) -- (L1)
--  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

-- Let's say, at this point, @TableIWantRecordsFrom ... contains the text 'Person'
--                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

-- assuming that is the case then...
-- these two queries are supposed to return the same results:

SELECT top 3 fname,lname,mi,department,floor FROM Person
--                                                ^^^^^^
SELECT top 3 fname,lname,mi,department,floor FROM @TableIWantRecordsFrom -- (L2)
--                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From reading all the responses and answers, it appears that this kind of maneuver can't be done - unless - you use dynamic SQL which...

- **can be** a bit of a pain to create and maintain and
- **can be** more work to create than the time it "saves" you in the future.

================================================================

There are **other languages** where this can be done... in literally, two lines of code (see (L1) and (L2) in above code) and not having to do a lot of formatting and editing.)

(I've done it before - there is another language where all you'd need is L1 and L2...)

================================================================

It is unfortunate that SQL Server will not do this without going to a decent amount of effort...

- first write your SQL then
- test it to make sure it does, in fact, *work* then
- frame each line with tick marks and then escape your ticks that are now inside THOSE tick marks
- declare the variable
- set the variable to the sql statement you ticked above
- (I may be missing some additional steps)
- Oh, and then, if you ever need to maintain it
- you need to either, be very careful and just edit it right there, as is, and hope you get it all just right -or- you may have saved a copy of it... un-ticked and un-variablized so you can edit the "real" sql and then when you're done you can RE DO these steps... again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
DECLARE @vTableName table(TableName varchar(50))

insert into @vTableName 
SELECT TableName FROM qms_Types WHERE Id = 1

SELECT * FROM @vTableName
```

Comment: This query returns my table name, not the content of my table :(

Comment: it will return the content of the TableName column.
what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this is through Dynamic SQL which refers to the practice of creating a T-SQL text and executing it using the [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) (or simply [`exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx))

Here is a helpful link about dynamic sql [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

You should really think whether or not this is a case for dynamic sql or if there is another way for you to perform this operation.