# Must declare the table variable SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing to make it easier for other techs to fix a database issue.

The goal of this query is so the techs only have to copy paste and provided 3 values but I'm running into a error

> Must declare the table variable "@fromArchives".

```
DECLARE @maxIdentityValue   INT
DECLARE @selectId   varchar(60)
DECLARE @fromArchives   varchar(60)
DECLARE @tableDBCC  varchar(60)

SET @selectId = someColumn --This is a column in the @fromArchives
SET @fromArchives = OrderArchives --This is a table
SET @tableDBCC = Orders --This is the table to fix


SET @maxIdentityValue =
(SELECT MAX(@selectId)
FROM @fromArchives) + 1


DBCC CHECKIDENT 
(@tableDBCC, RESEED, @maxIdentityValue)
GO
```

any ideas?

Comment: Trying to set it to the table name those 3 SET with comments are all just to be names of the table or column

Comment: I think this will require dynamic sql, you can't variablize (is that a word?) a table name.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that you're trying to select from a `varchar`.  If you want to select from the table of that name I believe you will need to use dynamic sql.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030486/sql-server-2008-select-from-variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All tablename should be static in sql query.

If you want to use dynamic table or column names, you should generate the full SQL dynamically, and use `sp_executesql` or `EXEC(sql)` to execute it.

```
DECLARE @fromArchives varchar(60)
SET @fromArchives = OrderArchives --This is a table
EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @fromArchives)
```

<kbd>[Refer This Dynamic SQL Article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, You cant use table name as Variable, if so Use Dynamic SQL

Comment: aha i see why is that though?