# mySQL SELECT values from a TABLE where the TABLE name is based on a field value

Tags: mysql

Here's are very simplified versions of my tables.

```
[stock_adjust]
id
batch_table_name
batch_id
adjustment_reason
qty

[ingredient_batch]
id
batch_name
...lots of other columns

[product_batch]
id
batch_name
...lots of other columns

[packaging_batch 
id
batch_name
...lots of other columns
```

*stock_adjust* contains the name of the correct batch table in the column *batch_table_name* which will either be "ingredient_batch", "product_batch" or "packaging_batch". I need to get the values from the correct batch table for each entry. The pseudo code for this would look something like the following:

```
SELECT sa.id, sa.adjustment_reason, sa.qty, batch.batch_name 
FROM stock_adjust AS sa, [sa.batch_table_name] AS batch
WHERE sa.batch_id=batch.id
```

I have tried to simplify the description and tables as much as possible, hopefully I haven't simplified it too much and the above makes sense?

I have found several questions regarding similar issues to the following, but they either do not work correctly in this situation or I am not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Have you tried prepared statements?

Comment: I am trying to get my head around prepared statements right now, but I still haven't worked out how that will help? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27542990/2520628
If required, I will try to post a solution

Comment: Thanks Tejashwi. I am sure that prepared statements are not as complicated as they look but I still can't get my head around how I can create one that helps me here.

Comment: Let me try if I can create some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would recommend updating your database schema, here's an approach that could work for you given your scenario:

```
select sa.id, b.batch_name
from stock_adjust sa join (
  select id, batch_name, 'ingredient_batch' table_name from ingredient_batch
  union all
  select id, batch_name, 'product_branch' table_name from product_branch
  union all
  select id, batch_name, 'packaging_batch' table_name from packaging_batch
  ) b on sa.batch_table_id = b.id and b.table_name = sa.batch_table_name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6983a/3)

Comment: I agree with the suggestions provided by @sgeddes that OP should update database schema, but this query can be a real pain if the data in `ingredient_batch` `product_branch` `packaging_batch` is large.

Comment: Thanks sgeddes' and  Tejashwi. I had tried UNION before I posted this but couldn't get it working. I looked at it again after sgeddes post and tweaked what I had which now works. I agree about schema. However, the db is massive and has over 2 years of very interlinked data in it. The tables are also much more complicated than my simple example above. I could update the schema and write some PHP script to juggle all of the data around but if I miss any links between tables then it will really mess things up for the 40+ people using this every day. I would not be popular I messed that up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee a `dynamic query` could be the solution. Check this answer  [SELECT * FROM @variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030486/sql-server-2008-select-from-variable)