# Trying to find views with and without rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 226 views in our database, and we would like to find out which ones are empty. I have written the code below and the output says only that every view contains rows, when I know that is not true.

I started by using this code to find out if some of the views had rows:

```
select case when exists (select 1 from a_view)
      then 'contains rows' 
      else 'doesnt contain rows'
```

This worked fine but I am trying to wrap this code inside a looping query that will give me this output for every view. The code below is as far as I have gotten and as I stated above, the output just says 'contains rows' for every view, which is not true.

```
declare @counter int

--- table variable for input
declare @tblname table(name_ varchar(400))

--- table variable for output
declare @outtbl table(name_ varchar(400))

--- the number of views present to end while loop
declare @viewNumber int = (select count(*) from sys.views)

--- inserting data into table variable
insert into @tblname
select name from sys.views

set @counter = 1

while exists (select name_ from @tblname) and @counter <= @viewNumber
    begin
        insert into @outtbl select case when exists (select 1 from @tblname)
              then 'contains rows' 
              else 'doesnt contain rows' 
           end
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end

select * from @outtbl
```

Comment: `select 1 from @tblname` => Table name cannot be parametrized - http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table

Comment: So this is impossible?

Comment: With dynamic SQL it is possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 SELECT \* FROM @variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030486/sql-server-2008-select-from-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a somewhat manual but relatively simple method:

```
select replace('
select ''[name]'' as view_name, (case when exists (select 1 from [name]) then ''contains rows'' else ''does not contain rows'' end)
',
               '[name]', v.name)
from sys.views v;
```

You can run this in SSMS.  Then just copy all the rows into a new query window and run the query.  You can add `union all` between the queries so all are returned in a single result set.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=46057f25a60f94acb87f064689316b35) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Oops: `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 - The multi-part identifier "v.name" could not be bound` -> need to drop `v.` or add `v` alias. Also, the "doesn't" goes wrong... Finally, for a view with a million rows, it will show "contains rows" a million times...

Comment: @PeterB . . . (1) typo, fixed.  (2) don't generate SQL with single quotes embedded in strings.  (3) this now produces only one row for each view.

Comment: I cannot make the code work that is outputted from this code above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Well for me it doesnt like the object, or view name, at the beginning of the select statement. Im getting:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2                                                                                
     Invalid object name 'VIEWSYSTEMLABORATORYINFORMATION'.

Comment: OK i just needed to add the schema info into the query above and it worked. I took the schema and the view name from information.views and concatenated the two together in place of [name]. Nice work-around!

Answer (score 0):

A different idea, but still using Dynamic SQL to get a count, is to create a bunch of `INSERT` statements to insert the counts into a temporary table, and finally retrieve that count:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE #ViewRows (Viewname sysname,' +  NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'             RowNum int);' +  NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'INSERT INTO #ViewRows (ViewName, RowNum)'+ NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(V.TABLE_SCHEMA + N'.' + v.TABLE_NAME,'''') + N', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(V.TABLE_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(v.TABLE_NAME) + N');'
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS V
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'') +  +  NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'SELECT * FROM #ViewRows;';
SELECT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: the only way you can do what you're after *is* with Dynamic SQL though, @Thomas_. if you don't understand it, then please ask about what about you don't and i'll be happy to explain what it does.

Comment: Well there is another issue where I only have Select privileges on this database. Though we will be working to get our own schema where myself and our epidemiologist can create tables, views, stored procedures, etc. So does dynamic SQL require stored procedures?

Comment: No, it doesn't @Thomas_ ; apart from `sp_executesql` which is a **system** SP; and denying a user access to `sp_executesql` would very likely result in a breaking change. It uses the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects, which you will have access to, and be able to see data for objects you can `SELECT` from.

Comment: Ok great. So what does dynamic SQL do? Would it paramaterize the the table variable @tblname?

Comment: I went ahead and ran this code and it ran for 5 minutes before I just stopped it. Should it take so long to run?

Comment: On my environment, against a database with over 1,500 views and low useage, it took about 19 seconds, @Thomas_ . Will try it against a much larger database we have, with high usage for you. If it's taking that long that suggests a very poorly performing server, or a database with some very poor statistics or indexing.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by would it parametrise the table variable `@tblname`? It's looking at **every** view in your database.

Comment: *P.s. Took 2:40 to complete against a database with 5,600 Views. And yes, I* really *do have a database with that many views; welcome to the world of openGI.*

Comment: Oh wow ya that is certainly a problem on our side. The servers are remotely located and owned by a contracted vendor. Performance is an issue these days and it is something that we would like to address.

Comment: Thats some serious data you are working with! Cool website. Insurance, yes that is a common use for very large datasets these days!